# Homebrew: `brew uses --installed gcc` does not give any result

Tags: r, gcc, dependencies, homebrew

I would want to get the list of installed packages that depend on gcc (installed with homebrew). When I try:

`brew uses --installed gcc`

it gives no result. And if I check e.g. r's dependencies with `brew deps r`, it returns `gcc` (among others). So I assume `brew uses` should at least return the value `r`.

Did anyone encounter a similar problem and could shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an authoritative answer, but it appears to me that this is because `r` depends on `:fortran`, which is some kind of virtual dependency that can be resolved in different ways.  `brew deps` answers the question, what would I need to install before installing this formula.  And in your case it decides that installing `gcc` is a way to satisfy the `:fortran` requirement.  But the reverse is apparently not supported: It doesn't know just from looking at `gcc` that this can be used to resolve the virtual dependency `:fortran`.  This is somewhat plausible if one considers the way that virtual dependencies are implemented in Homebrew.  Usually, it just looks around in the file system to see if a required binary is available (including ones supplied outside of Homebrew), but it doesn't establish a formula dependency link once it finds a candidate.

(In fact, this case might be even more complex.  If you look at `brew deps r --tree`, you will see that the dependency is actually on `:gcc`, which is another level of virtual dependency.)

Although not directly related to your question, also note that `deps` by default is recursive but `uses` is not.  So in order to get a symmetric picture, you'd need to use `deps -1` or `uses --recursive`.